# How to determine if symbol is bounded (var defined)?

Tags: clojure

I'm looking at the `bound?` fn but that's not what I need. 
I need a simple predicate to determine if some var is defined with given symbol (or string).

For example:

```
(def a 1)
(def b)

(bounded? 'a)
=> true
(bounded? 'b)
=> false
(bounded? 'c)
=> fasle

;or maybe for given name as string

(bounded? "a")
```

What's the best way to do this?